# Create SQL database from dict with different features in python

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
base = {}
base['id1'] = {'apple':2, 'banana':4,'coconut':1}
base['id2'] = {'apple':4, 'pear':8}
base['id3'] = {'banana':1, 'tomato':2}
....
base['idN'] = {'pineapple':1}
```

I want to create a SQL database to store it. I normally use `sqlite` but here the number of variables (features in the dict) is not the same for all ids and I do not know all of them thus I cannot use the standard procedure.

Does someone know an easy way to do it ?

Comment: have two columns `_fruit` and `_quantity` , add all fruits to `_fruit` and quantity to `_quantity` though if you wanna total of apples then use update if it's already in table

Answer (score 0):

ids will get duplicated if you use the sql i would suggest use postgres as it has a jsonfield ypu can put your data there corresponding to each key. Assuming you are not constrained to use SQL.